# Type inference of constructor is throwing error when class has Type parameter

Tags: java, generics

New to Generics concept and I am facing issue in below code

```
public class Main
{
    static class GenericCheck<X>{
        private X x;
        <T> GenericCheck(T t){
            x=t;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        public void display(){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericCheck<String> genericCheck = new GenericCheck("sathish worked");

    }
}
```

Error throwing:

```
Main.java:14: error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to X
            x=t;
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no relation between the unknown type T and X. Maybe you shouldn't redefine a type T in your constructor but just use the generic type X of your class

Comment: What are you trying to do with your `T` type?

Comment: Trying to understand how to initialize Type inference with Type parameter in the generic class.

Comment: In General ,Not related to question why i am getting negative mark for the question as i said new to concept. :(

Comment: I wondered about that too. I think people didn't really "get" the question. Your comment above responding to my question about `T` clarified it a lot for me. People voted early, though, before that was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's nothing relating `T` to `X`, there's no way for the compiler to know they're related to one another.

It's not clear what you're trying to do with `T`, `X` is sufficient:

```
public class Main
{
    static class GenericCheck<X>{
        private X x;
        GenericCheck(X t){ // *** Use `X` directly
            x=t;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        public void display(){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericCheck<String> genericCheck = new GenericCheck<>("sathish worked");
        // Need to provide generic here too ----------------^^  That shorthand form is fine

    }
}
```

But if you want `T`, it will need to be related to `X` in some way, for example:

```
public class Main
{
    static class GenericCheck<X>{
        private X x;
        <T extends X> GenericCheck(T t){
        //^^^^^^^^^^
            x=t;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        public void display(){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericCheck<String> genericCheck = new GenericCheck<>("sathish worked");
        // -------------------------------------------------^^

    }
}
```

...but there's no reason to do that unless you have some other constraint on `T`, since you can already provide a subclass of `X` during construction with the class in the first code block above. This works fine, for instance:

```
class Base {
}
class Derived extends Base {
}
public class Example
{
    static class GenericCheck<X>{
        private X x;
        GenericCheck(X t){
            x=t;
            System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void display(){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericCheck<Base> genericCheck = new GenericCheck<>(new Derived());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I  want to know  logic here, for ex: GenericCheck<String> genericCheck = new GenericCheck<>("sathish worked");                              ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         X-> String and T-> String  data type .Fundamentally we can assign the value with same data type.But in this case, Type parameter is not getting assigned to same data type values.

Comment: @sathishkannan - As I said, your `GenericCheck` class has to tell the compiler how the `X` and `T` types relate to each other so it knows it's okay to assign type `T` to type `X`. It can't know that in the general case. Yes, it would be true if you supplied `String` for both types, but it wouldn't be true other types. For `GenericCheck` to compile, it has to be known to **always** be true (by constraining `T` such that it's assignable to `X`).

Answer (score -3):

JVM can not do x=t if there is not any relationship declared.
You can override the error though with explicit casting like

```
x=(Object)T;
```